# Code that should count all pairs in an array doesnt work corectly

Tags: java, arrays

My code should count all pairs in a given array. 
For example if there is an array: 2,3,4,2,3,2,2,
the number of pairs is: (2,2), (2,2), (3,3) -> 3 pairs.

This is the task on codewars.com.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-all-pairs-1/train/java

But my code dont pass random test and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
public static int duplicates(int[] array)
{
    if (array.length == 0 || array.length == 1)
        return 0; 

    int numberOfPairs = 0;
    int counted;

    for (int num : array) {
        counted = 0;
        for (int num2 : array) {
            if (num == num2) {
                counted++;
                if (counted >= 2) {
                    numberOfPairs++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return numberOfPairs / 2;
}
```

Comment: what *does* it return? Does it error? Does it return the wrong number?

Comment: Your definition of pair is that a number can only be paired with one other number. In other words, when you find a pair of numbers they must be removed from the remaining numbers, otherwise you'll end up using the same number twice.

Comment: I see your algorithm probably works with your sample input.  It breaks badly if you simply add another 2 to the end of your input.

Comment: I would use a HashMap to store entries of the array with their count and divide it by 2. If you want I can write a snippet.
You are wrong because you are running the second loop from the beginning. Drop the syntactic sugar of for each loop and write the traditional for loop and start your inner loop from the next index of outer loop.

Comment: @Gendarme It's worth mentioning you cannot remove from the array while in the loop unless you are using an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `Arrays.sort` to make it easier.

Here is the logic I used step by step:

1. First the array is sorted in ascending order before the loop.
2. In the loop, check to see if the next number is the same as the
   current number.
3. If they are the same, increment the count and iterate the loop by 2 to skip the number that was
   already used.
4. If they are *not* the same iterate the loop only once because the next value
       has not been used yet.

Here is the implementation of the logic below:

```
public static int duplicates(int[] array)
{
   int numberOfPairs = 0;

   Arrays.sort(array);
   for (int k = 0; k < array.length - 1; k++) 
   {
       if (array[k] == array[k + 1])
       {
           numberOfPairs++;
           k++;
       }
   }
   return numberOfPairs;
}
```

I tested it with a few different cases and it seems to be working.

**Test Run:**

```
int [] arr = {2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 6 ,7 ,7, 7};
System.out.println("Duplicates: " + duplicates(arr));
```

> Duplicates: 7

Answer (score 0):

I would write in this way

```
public static int duplicates(int[] array)
{
    if (array.length == 0 || array.length == 1)
        return 0; 

    int numberOfPairs = 0;
    boolean used[] = new boolean[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) used[i] = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if( used[i] ) continue;
        for (int j = i+1; j< array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
              used[i] = used[j] = true;
              numberOfPairs++;
              break;
           }
        }
    }

    return numberOfPairs;
}
```

Seems to be working on my machine.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code
no need to hash or sort

```
 public static int duplicates(int[] array)
{
if (array.length == 0 || array.length == 1)
    return 0; 

int numberOfPairs = 0;

for (int i=0;i+1<array.length;i++) {
    for (int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j]) {
            numberOfPairs++;
            array[j]=array[i+1];
            i++;
            break;
        }

    }

}

return numberOfPairs ;
}
```

i just replace the j element with i+1 element and increment i by one because tp to avoid the duplicate of j element

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm takes O(n^2) and others who use `Arrays.sort` take O(nlog(n)) time. If you are allowed to take O(n) space this algorithm can do it in O(n) time complexity.

```
public static int duplicates(int[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      map.compute(array[i], (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e: map.entrySet()) {
      if (e.getValue() > 1) {
        count += e.getValue() / 2;
      }
    }
    return count;
}
```

You will have to import java.util.Map, HashMap for this result. It is not the same as your approach but I think adding this here would make you think about this approach too. Happy coding!